# How to access request url pk from throttle class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie to Django, and I am building a Django application that uses REST API. I have a throttle class, and I want to restrict users to send more than 5 number of invitations to the same user in one minute. I send a user ID with the URL.

I should access pk to use it for the caching operation. How can I access the pk from the throttle class?

> For example: api/users/3299143165471965406/resend-invitation-email/
>
> **Pk will be**: 3299143165471965406

**views.py**

```
    @decorators.action(methods=['post'], detail=True, serializer_class=None,
                       permission_classes=[core_permissions.IsCompanyAdmin],
                       url_path='resend-invitation-email', throttle_classes=[throttles.ResendInvitationThrottle])
    def resend_invitation_email(self, request, pk=None):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        if user.invitation_status == User.INVITATION_STATUS_ACCEPTED or user.invitation_status is None:
            raise ValidationError("This user is already registered.")
        else:
            invitations_tasks.send_invitation_email.delay(pk)
            return response.Response(status=200)
```

**throttle:**

```
class ResendInvitationThrottle(SimpleRateThrottle):
    scope = 'invitation'

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        invited_user_id = 1  # Here I should use PK
        return self.cache_format % {
            'scope': self.scope,
            'ident': invited_user_id
        }
```

**Edit:**

> I solved it by using: `invited_user_id = view.kwargs['pk']`

Comment: Thank you for your response. ```self.request.kwargs['pk']``` throws exception: 'Request' object has no attribute 'kwargs'.

Comment: Sorry, `self.request.kwargs` is completely wrong, it was late at night when I wrote that. Good to see you figured it out. You can add your own answer then mark it as accepted if you like.